# Razorpay payment link success response sending empty object or string

Tags: json, error-handling, payment-gateway, razorpay

uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse ()

$(document).ready(
function () {

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var email = $("#email").val();
  var number = $("#number").val();


  $.ajax(
    {
      type: "POST",
      url: "create-payment-link.php",
      data: { user_name: name, user_email: email, user_number: number },
      success: function (data) {

        console.info(JSON.parse(data));

      }
    }
  );

});
```

}

);

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.